# Add constraint before view is seen?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to center an arrow button with a `width = 40` in the middle of my screen using constraints programmatically.

My code works if I call it in `viewDidAppear` but crashes in `viewDidLoad`.

**Having it in `viewDidAppear` is an eye sore since you see the screen and then see the button jump to the middle of the screen.** Any idea how to make it set up before the view is shown?

I might add this is a subview so I am calling `centerArrow()` from a `viewController` whose view is not the same view.

So inside the `viewController`:

```
let pview = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Profile", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! ProfileView


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    pview.centerArrow()
}
```

And inside `ProfileView` which inherits `UIView`:

```
func centerArrow()
{
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let width = (screenSize.width / 2) - 20
    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: arrowButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: width)
    self.addConstraint(constraint)
}
```

Comment: Uh... `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX`?

Comment: @nhgrif without going into much detail that would not work for me because the subview was actually larger than the screen.

Comment: That's irrelevant.  If the view's need to be centered with each other, it doesn't matter how wide they are or whether or not they entirely fit on the screen... that doesn't effect `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `viewDidLayoutSubViews`,  that might provide the timing you are looking for in this case.